# How to make new dataframe of every second or third id with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, with id, username, and date.  I sorted the data frame by id.
How to make new data frames, that contains every second or third id?

Here is my code where I made a Data Frame and I sorted it by id:

```
import pandas as pd

id = ['11', '11', '11', '15', '15', '15', '23', '23', '25']
username = ['usera','userb','userc','userd','usere','userf','userd','usere','userf']
date = ['2021-05-04','2021-05-05','2021-05-05','2021-05-06','2021-06-07','2021-06-08','2021-07-09','2021-03-09','2021-04-10']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'username': username, 'date': date})


dx = df.sort_values(by=['id'], ignore_index=True) #Sort because the dataframe not sorted. by default
print(dx) 

Here is some expected output:

  #dx = get every second value
   id username        date
0  11    usera  2021-05-04
1  11    userb  2021-05-05
2  11    userc  2021-05-05

6  23    userd  2021-07-09
7  23    usere  2021-03-09
....



# Get every third by id:

  id username        date
0  11    usera  2021-05-04
1  11    userb  2021-05-05
2  11    userc  2021-05-05
8  25    userf  2021-04-10
.....
```

In my task the user names and the rows here are not relevant, just the id's.
I need to get every second or third id in the same dataframe.

Comment: can you double check your example output?

Comment: I need to get every second item by ID, not by row!
Could you give me some hints on how to do this way?

Comment: how do you have `11    usera  2021-05-04` in two groups?

Comment: The user names here are not relevant, just the id's.

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupby` the cumcount of the groups and transform to dict:

```
dfs = dict(list(df.groupby(df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1))))
```

output:

```
{1:    id username        date
 0  11    usera  2021-05-04
 3  15    userd  2021-05-06
 6  23    userd  2021-07-09
 8  25    userf  2021-04-10,
 2:    id username        date
 1  11    userb  2021-05-05
 4  15    usere  2021-06-07
 7  23    usere  2021-03-09,
 3:    id username        date
 2  11    userc  2021-05-05
 5  15    userf  2021-06-08}
```

Then each value in the `dfs` dictionary is a sub dataframe:

```
>>> dfs[1] # 1st occurence
   id username        date
0  11    usera  2021-05-04
3  15    userd  2021-05-06
6  23    userd  2021-07-09
8  25    userf  2021-04-10
```

Comment: And how to make a new DataFrame?
df = dfs[1]

Comment: Yes, although you don't need to assign it to a variable, it is perfectly fine to use the dictionary (especially if you have many subdataframes)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately, it is not good for me.
I need to get every second item by ID, not by row!
Could you give me some hints how to do this way?

Comment: This is why I asked you to check your example; I found it a bit ambiguous

Comment: Yeah my example is good. :D

Comment: Then sorry I don't get it

Comment: The user names here are not relevant, just the id's.